# "IPN Delivery Failed. HTTP error code 404: Not Found" error is showing if used codeigniter controller to listen IPN notification

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

"**IPN Delivery Failed. HTTP error code 404: Not Found**" error is showing if i used codeigniter controller to listen instant payment notifications but same thing working fine in core php [ file specified in root folder].

please help ...

Comment: What answer you want, when you don't show us your CODE, where is your problem located? 404 means that this page is NOT EXISTING so perhaps your url or controller is set wrong..

Answer (score 0):

If you have CSRF turned on it can cause the problem as the IPN is POST request and there isn't naturally csrf token included.